# Creating a postgresql trigger function to update a Linestring geometry column

Tags: postgresql, join, postgis, point, database-trigger

I'm new to postgresql with postgis extension. I'm trying to create a trigger function that updates a geometry column geom (Linestring) in table_2 whenever I insert or update site_a, site_b in it. These latter columns are foreign keys referencing site_code in table_1.

table_1:

```
 site_code |                        geom
-----------+----------------------------------------------------
 MIT03     | 0101000020E61000009B55BFC8CDF8174054483DD5C9254240
 BAS33     | 0101000020E6100000345EEA4A00A61A4095FAE019BDDD4140
```

table_2:

```
 link_id | site_a | site_b | geom
---------+--------+--------+------
      72 | BAS33  | MIT03  |
      57 | AI4402 | MIT03  |
```

Here is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_line() RETURNS TRIGGER
AS
$$
BEGIN
UPDATE links SET geom =ST_MakeLine((SELECT sites.geom FROM links JOIN sites ON site_code=NEW.site_a),(SELECT sites.geom FROM links JOIN sites ON site_code=NEW.site_b)) WHERE link_id=NEW.link_id;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And the trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_create_line
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF site_a, site_b
ON links
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_line();
```

I can't make this function work.

Answer (score 0):

I could manage to make the function work, the issue came from the SELECT queries inside ST_MakeLine; both returned many rows. 
By adding a LIMIT 1

```
(SELECT sites.geom FROM links JOIN sites ON site_code=site_a WHERE site_a=NEW.site_a LIMIT 1),(SELECT sites.geom FROM links JOIN sites ON site_code=site_b WHERE site_b=NEW.site_b LIMIT 1))
```

the problem was solved partially since the function updated all rows in table_2.
A condition `WHERE link_id=NEW.link_id` is added at the end of the update and things are fine now.